# Converting nested for loop to while loop in Python

Tags: python, loops

I am a beginner in python and I have used what I know from eclipse to write 4 nested for loops. I would like to condense my loops into a while loop but I am unsure how to do so. Could someone please help me? Here's my code:

```
import sys
n = int(sys.argv[1])

# step 1 four nested loops
for a in range(1, n + 1):
          a3 = a*a*a
          if a3 > n:
                    break
          for b in range(a + 1, n + 1):
                    b3 = b*b*b
                    if a3 + b3 > n:
                              break
                    for c in range(a + 1, n + 1):
                              c3 = c*c*c
                              if c3 > a3 + b3:
                                        break
                              for d in range(c + 1, n + 1):
                                        d3 = d*d*d
                                        if c3 + d3 > a3 + b3:
                                                  break
                                           if a3 + b3 == c3 + d3:                         
                                             print str(a3 + b3), " = ", a, "^3", " + ", b, "^3", " = ", c, "^3", " + ", d, "^3"
```

Comment: What..... is this program suppose to achieve?

Comment: Instead of using `for a in range(1, n+1)`, do `a = 1; while a < n + 1; a += 1` and so on...

Comment: You have four `for`-loops nested for a reason. A `while`-loop cannot magically replace four loops into one. You can only remove the innermost loop, because you can algebraically deduce the value of `d` when you know `a`, `b` and `c`.